# Check whether two lists are identical up to numerical error

Tags: python, list, precision

I have two algorithms that theoretically should perform the same task, and I want to check if they really do.

They each returns a large list containing a mixture of datatypes (numbers, lists, strings). I want to check if the two lists are identical.

The simple method is `assert list1 == list2`. However, due to numerical errors, sometimes an element in `list1` is `5` and the corresponding element in `list2` is `5.000003`. This still triggers the assertion `False`, but I want to ignore such small error.

How to implement this "check for identity up to numerical errors"?

I think the fact that the lists contain a mixture of datatypes (not just numbers) complicates the problem.

Comment: Just create a recursive fuzzy comparison function.  Do the exact same thing you'd do if you were performing an exact comparison, except when you encounter a pair of numbers, perform a fuzzy comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic formula would be something like:

```
len(list1) == len(list2) and all(is_close(a, b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

with some function `is_close` that you use to compare two elements, maybe along the lines of:

```
def is_close(a, b):
    return a == b or (
        isinstance(a, (float, int)) and isinstance(b, (float, int))
        and abs(a - b) < 0.000005
    )
```

potentially with other exceptions to the general `a == b` rule for different data types.  It could even be defined recursively to handle nested data:

```
def is_close(a, b):
    return a == b or (
        isinstance(a, (float, int)) and isinstance(b, (float, int))
        and abs(a - b) < 0.000005
    ) or (
        isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list)
        and len(a) == len(b)
        and all(is_close(*z) for z in zip(a, b))
    ) or (
        isinstance(a, dict) and isinstance(b, dict)
        and a.keys() == b.keys()
        and all(is_close(a[k], b[k]) for k in a)
    )  # etc?
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can create a custom list class and overload the `==` operator.

```
from collections import UserList

class CustomList(UserList):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if CUSTOM LOGIC HERE:
            return true
        else:
            return false
```

You could then use the CustomList as you would a built-in Python list.

```
my_custom_list = CustomList([1, 2, 3])
```

Since you only overload the `__eq__` method, it will behave like a normal list except that it will have custom logic for comparing lists together.

Comment: Note that it's generally advisable to subclass [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userlist-objects) instead of subclassing `list` directly

Comment: Thank you @Brian61354270. I will update my original response to reflect.